# How do I fix a floating div inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I don't really know how to put it in words but I do have pictures which will quite give you an idea of my problem. Seems like float is giving me the problem/

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

This is my problem:
[image]

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  background: #C52C2C;
}
.images div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
#portfolio {
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  heigth: 400px;
  background-color: #c62828;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <!-- Top Boxes -->
  <div class="box-1 left"></div>
  <div class="box-2 left"></div>
  <div class="box-3 left"></div>
  <!-- Bottom Boxes -->
  <div class="box-4 left"></div>
  <div class="box-5 left"></div>
  <div class="box-6 left"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is change the height of the portfolio section but when I change the height, nothing changes. If I remove the boxes then I can change the height. How would I fix this?

Thank you if you well understood this.

Comment: There is no div with `id="portfolio"`

Comment: depending on which browsers you're looking to support, recommend looking into flexbox.

Comment: The code you posted is too minimal. There is no `#portfolio`

Comment: I didn't include that, oops.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of impropper value of the `display` property for `View More` element. You should set it to be:

```
view_more{ display: block; } // Please replace **view_more** with the correct value to select the element
```

Also do that for the downward arrow.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you mean something like this?** 
https://jsfiddle.net/xsjjo654/1/

---

Code Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            h1.title {
                text-align: center;
                color: white;
                font-size: 40pt;
                margin: 5px auto;
            }

            #portfolio {
                overflow: auto;
                clear: both;
                min-height: 400px;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #c62828;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #portfolio > .wrapper {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #portfolio > .wrapper > section {
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            section.side-left {
                text-align: right;
            }

            section.side-right {
                text-align: left;
            }

            section.side-center {
                width: 930px;
            }

            .images {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .images .box {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                background-color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                margin: 1px;
            }

            .button {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: transparent;
                outline: 0;
                border: none;
            }

            .button.round, .button.round-alt {
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                font-size: 30px;
            }

            .button.round {
                background-color: white;
                color: #c62828;
            }

            .button.round-alt {
                border: 2px solid white;
                color: white;
                margin: 30px;
            }

            .button.square {
                border: 2px solid white;
                color: white;
                font-size: 14pt;
                padding: 12px 30px;
                margin: 40px auto;
            }

            /* (c) 2016 David@Refoua.me, www.Refoua.me */
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="portfolio">
            <h1 class="title">
                Portfolio
            </h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <section class="side-left">
                    <button class="button round prev">
                    &larr;
                    </button>
                </section>
                <section class="side-center">
                    <div class="images">
                        <!-- Top Boxes -->
                        <div class="box"></div>
                        <div class="box"></div>
                        <div class="box"></div>
                        <br>
                        <!-- Bottom Boxes -->
                        <div class="box"></div>
                        <div class="box"></div>
                        <div class="box"></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="side-right">
                    <button class="button round prev">
                    &rarr;
                    </button>
                </section>
            </div>
            <button class="button square more">
                View More...
            </button>
            <br>
            <button class="button round-alt down">
                &darr;
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: @JesseZambrano You're welcome! Maybe consider upvoting it and marking it as 'the accepted answer' so the others in the future can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try Bootstrap. It let's you play around with some cool grid functionality AND it's RESPONSIVE!

```
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
             rel="stylesheet">
                <style>
                    .inner { 
                                height:350px; 
                                background-color:white;
                                margin-top:5px;
                                margin-left:-25px;}
                    body {background-color:red;}
                </style>
            <body>


            <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <div class='inner'></div>
                            <div class='inner'></div>
                </div>

                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <div class='inner'></div>
                            <div class='inner'></div>
                </div>

                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-4'>
                            <div class='inner'></div>
                            <div class='inner'></div>
                </div>
            </div>

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
 3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Output: http://s28.postimg.org/9y69346tp/test.png You can add more rows later if you're going to refresh your pictures from database automatically.

Hope that helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you give a width to images and margin:auto it should center much easier :)

```css
body {
  background: #C52C2C;
}
.images {
  width:912px;
  margin:auto;
  }
.images div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}
#portfolio {
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  heigth: 400px;
  background-color: #c62828;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <!-- Top Boxes -->
  <div class="box-1 left"></div>
  <div class="box-2 left"></div>
  <div class="box-3 left"></div>
  <!-- Bottom Boxes -->
  <div class="box-4 left"></div>
  <div class="box-5 left"></div>
  <div class="box-6 left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this: [clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html)

The problem here is that your container doesn't take the height of the inner boxes in consideration, so if you add the clearfix to it that will do the trick